# Custom "cellfilter" in Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-grid

I am working with the ng-grid in Angular js.
I have this line of code which defines the type of filter added.

```
  columnDefs: [{field:'date', displayName:'Birth Date', cellFilter:'date:\"dd MMM yyyy\"'},
                    {field:'pre', displayName:'Prev', cellFilter:'number'}, 
                    {field:'fct', displayName:'Fct', cellFilter:'number'},
                    {field:'act', displayName:'Act', cellFilter:'number'}
                    {field:'imp', displayName:'Important', cellFilter:'number'}]
    };
```

the Important column has values "H" "L" and "M". By normal(alphabetical) sorting I can achieve a sort of H-L-M but is there a way to define a filter that sorts as **"H-M-L"**.

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom sort function:

```
    var result = 1;
    var test="HML";
    function impSortFn(a, b) {
    a=test.indexOf(a);
    b=test.indexOf(b);
    if (a == b) return 0;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return result;
    }

    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',

    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name'
    }, {
      field: 'age',
      displayName: 'Age'
    }, {
      field: 'imp',
      displayName: 'Important',
      sortFn: impSortFn
    }]
```

[See this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W4YSum?p=preview)

Comment: thanks a lot.. that works beautifully. But can you please explain me the functionality as impSortFn is not passing values of a and b. and where does the return conditions are validated?

Comment: The sortFN to which I assigned impSortFn (just a random name) is a callback that is executed while the ng-grid build-in sort function iterates over myData. It always send the actual value and the next value in a and b as parameters to this function. The return value of 0 or -1 is used by the sorter to whether shift this array position or leave it as it is and continue sorting. Since comparing letters H, M, L  to more or less will use the ascii values, I use the position in TEST string for sorting. tbc..

Comment: ... Validation does not actually happen. If an entry has a value other than H, M or L indexOf returns -1 which is the same as false (eg. don't sort this entry). Returning result is not really required but it may spare you a warning the this function MIGHT somehow have no return value. Which will in fact never happen. Nearly all sorting functions in JS, jQuery or PHP work this way. I recomend some further reading like here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp. As they say on this side, this concept is a bit hard to grasp, but it makes perfect sense:-)